# Test coverage : how to include non-stub beans in coverage stats?

Tags: spring, unit-testing, code-coverage

When I run my unit tests, I don't want to start my MySQL server or RabbitMQ server, so I use an in-memory H2 db and I use a stub for my classes interacting with RabbitMQ :

This real class :

```java
@Service
@Slf4j
@Profile("!local-test")
public class MessageQueueSenderImpl implements MessageQueueSpi {

    private final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;
    private final Queue policeAssuranceQueue;
    private final PoliceAssuranceEventDtoMapper mapper;

    public MessageQueueSenderImpl(
            RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate,
            @Qualifier("policeAssuranceQueue") Queue policeAssuranceQueue,
            PoliceAssuranceEventDtoMapper mapper) {
        this.rabbitTemplate = rabbitTemplate;
        this.policeAssuranceQueue = policeAssuranceQueue;
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    @Override
    public void send(PoliceAssuranceEvent policeAssuranceEvent) {
        PoliceAssuranceEventDto policeAssuranceEventDto = mapper.toPoliceAssuranceEventDto(policeAssuranceEvent);
        log.info("Event sent : {}", policeAssuranceEventDto);       
        this.rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(policeAssuranceQueue.getName(), policeAssuranceEventDto);
    }
}
```

is replaced by this stub when my "local-test" profil is activated :

```java
@Service
@Slf4j
@Profile("local-test")
public class MessageQueueSenderLocalTestImpl implements MessageQueueSpi {

    @Override
    public void send(PoliceAssuranceEvent policeAssuranceCreatedEvent) {
        log.info("this event would be sent in a non local context : {}", policeAssuranceCreatedEvent);
    }
}
```

Now I would like to trace that this kind of test doesn't call my real "send" method, but in my Jacoco report, it says that my "message" package is 100% covered because it sees only the "stub" bean :
[image]

What would be the way to see that my real "send" method is not covered ?